# cannot resolve symbol 'coordinatorlayout' in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I was creating an android app and using coordinate layout, but I'm getting this error. Already added coordinate layout in build.gradle file and activity_main.xml file. The other class works fine only having issue in this single line of code. Is there any alternate way so that coordinate layout can be replaced with any other layout design.

This is my MainActivity.java file and already import the design layout. And so do in activity_main.xml file.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
    ...
    @BindView(R.id.image_preview)
    ImageView imagePreview;

    @BindView(R.id.tabs)
    TabLayout tabLayout;

    @BindView(R.id.viewpager)
    ViewPager viewPager;

    @BindView(R.id.coordinator_layout)  //here I'm getting error 'cannot resolve symbol 'coordinate layout''
    CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
    ...
    ...
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0-alpha05'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'




}
```

[build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBcJu.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add id for coordinate layout like `android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"` in your `<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`

so it will work

Comment: thank you. It was such a silly mistake I couldn't find

Answer (score 2):

It was fixed for me when I added

```
implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:<whatever the newest version is>'
```

to my modules dependency block.